# What do I need to change in the code of a wordpress site so that when I insert a link to a site, the link to that site appears and not another?

Tags: wordpress

Info: I moved wordpress from one site to another.

My actual site: guesstheelo.net, previous page bireport.cz

[Image here](https://i.ibb.co/dtJFXTP/Web.png)

Comment: Whenever you insert a new link in wordpress, it will link to the url you entered.

Comment: So did you mean existing links which where already present on the former domain? If so, how did they initially got inserted? If the links are part of the template, you should change the template. If they are inserted into posts, then you should change them either at database level or by using `str_replace` when getting the `post_content`. So it fully depends on the method they got inserted.